# How can detect tab key in onclick method in html?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a `select` in HTML:

```html
<select name="departamento" id="departamento" onclick="console.log('1')">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

When a user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key when the cursor is over an `option` the output in the `console` is `1` (it is calling the `onclick` listener).

I don't want that. I want to prevent the execution of `onclick` when user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. The solution can be in jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: you should be using preventDefault() ;

Comment: I don't know what you're attempting to do with this logic, but try using `change` instead of `click`. Also, use unobtrusive event handlers. `on*` event attributes are very outdated and should be avoided.

Comment: i tried change, but its not working. Always show me the message on the console. just wanna: when user press tab key don't execute onclick event.